# Autostart Samba on Boot Debian

Tags: boot, debian, samba

I installed Samba on my debian squeeze server but it doesnt start when I reboot it, I have to run it manually for it to start.

How can I make it so that when I start my server, samba starts automatically. I would rather do it without installing software

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As root enter:

`update-rc.d samba defaults`

This will install samba for the default runlevels

Answer (score 1):

Does chkconfig command work on Debian?

```
chkconfig smb on
```

---

Above command is tested on RHEL 6.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the init script which is starting the service smb from /etc/init.d to your /etc/rcX.d. Where X is your runlevel There is a program chkconfig which you first may have to install from the debian repository allowing you to do this quite easy (I am just not sure whether it is in the default installation):

```
apt-get install chkconfig
```

Now you can add the service smb to start with your system by typing as root:

```
chkconfig smb 3
```